# Solved - Setting DataGridColumnHeader template with predefined columns adds too much columns

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-core, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid:

```xml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Rejects}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="First column" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ItemsSource is bound to a property of my ViewModel called Rejects, which is an ObservableCollection of Dummy objects.

Here is the style called DataGridHeaderStyle:

```xml
    <Style x:Key="DataGridHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource EasternBlueBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DarkGreyBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0"/>

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">

                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <converters:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="5">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="SortArrow" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Width="2"
                               BorderThickness="1"
                               BorderBrush="{StaticResource EasternBlueBrush}"
                               Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Click to sort."/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CuriousBlueBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Text" Value="&#8595;"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Text" Value="&#8593;"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I was expecting to have only one column called "First column", but here is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aikiG.png)

As you can see, there is an other column called by the name of my ViewModel that appears. This doesn't happen when I remove the Template property.
Also, while this new column looks like the other one, it doesn't react when hovered.

**EDIT**

As I said under @ketan's answer, I was able to remove the weird column header by setting the DataContext of my DataGrid to {x:Null} and by setting the ItemsSource directly from the code-behind, which shows that the problem is linked to the DataGrid's DataContext, but I still need to keep it, any idea?

Also, here's the list I use as ItemsSource:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Dummy> Rejects { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dummy>()
        {
            new Dummy()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Prop1 = "A"
            },
            new Dummy()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Prop1 = "B"
            }
        };
```

**SOLUTION**

I finally found out what was going wrong. It's all linked to the Content property of my ContentPresenter inside the template: I set the Content property instead of the ContentSource. Thus, the solution is:

```xml
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
```

Comment: set datagrid AutoGenerateColumns = false

Comment: @ketan It's already set to false

Comment: please don't apply style and then check the output

Comment: @ketan when i don't the bug doesn't happen, it's linked to the template property of my style

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="gridDemo" ItemsSource="{Binding lst}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="gridDemo_Loaded_1" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="First column" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

pass the colun width to `*`

Comment: It worked but I also had to completely remove any reference of my viewmodel from my window, which I don't want. I also tried to set the DataContext of my DataGrid to {x:Null} and it worked as well, but I don't see why I would have to do that

Comment: above code work perfectly if i am not applying your style

Comment: are you sure you have added the `Width="*"` to First column ?

Comment: post your itemsource code Rejects. put debugger on itemsource where you passing the Reject data verify twice i think there is viewmodel will get add extra column so please check the list item you are passing to Grid. your result says itself compliancepaypal view model added by default

Comment: I edited my initial post with the code of my list. Also, while it worked using code-behind, I'm not satisfied with this and want to use my ViewModel with a binding, so I cannot debug this